# bootstrap - ul inside .well going outside, adding .row wrks but crossing boundary of container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my structure :

```
 <div class='container'>
    <div class='well>
       <ul class='pull-left unstyled'>
          <li>abc</li><li>def</li>
       </ul>

       <ul class='pull-right unstyled'>
          <li>abc</li><li>def</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

The result for above is, things inside ul are coming outside the 'well' (bottom).

So, I added class 'row', it worked but, whenever i add the class 'row' , it width is crossing the boundary of the container.

Comment: can you show live link ?

Comment: Is it a typo that you didn't close second `div` class attribute?

Comment: yeah type  here, not in original code

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing in the .well style that will clear the floats. If you have two floated items as you do with the two uls here then the container will collapse.

Have a look at this for the answer. 
http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html

Or just add this to the bottom of your style sheet.

```
.well:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: just adding the clearfix class solved the issue . By the way, thnks for answer . +1 .

Comment: Feel free to make this as the answer if it solved your problem, it will help other people find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add  to the div containing ul's, it will solve the problem .